# Postgresql - return json array in select query instead of comma separated values

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
`SELECT * FROM reports
        WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`
```

the column `type` has the following value: `"item1,item2,item3"`.

I want to return it as a JSON array: `["item1","item2","item3"]`

I tried this:

```
`SELECT *, string_to_array(type, ',') AS type FROM reports
        WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`
```

but I still get it as a plain comma separated string.

Is it possible to do this or I have to convert it manually on the server and not on the query itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the array as argument to [`to_jsonb()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html):

```
SELECT to_jsonb(string_to_array(type, ',')) AS type
FROM reports
```

JSON support was introduced in **Postgres 9.3** (json) and **9.4** (jsonb). In the older versions you can try to build a string representing a json array, e.g.:

```
with report(type) as (
    values ('item1,item2,item3')
)

select '[' || regexp_replace(type, '([^,]+)', '"\1"', 'g') || ']' as type
from report

           type            
---------------------------
 ["item1","item2","item3"]
(1 row)
```

Comment: What is the equiviliant for older Postgres versions such as 8.4?

Comment: Works in 2022 as well!